# What would the world be like if COVID-19 occurred in 1999?

Tags: alternate-history, alternate-reality, alternate-earth

You could pick whatever start date you feel is most interesting, applying the number and distribution of cases on that date to the same date 20 years ago. For example, imagine if we had the same global distribution of cases on 2000/01/01 as we actually had on 2020/01/01, with no assumptions about how it initially spread.

Interesting topics:

- **Technology**: Under self-isolation today, work and classes are mostly online. In 2000, online work and education were in its infancy.
- **Economics**: Relating to the above, the dot-com bubble was just reaching its peak (NASDAQ peaked March 10, 2000). How would the pandemic affect the bubble -- how severe would the recession be and what companies would be in a position to thrive in this new world?
- **Diplomacy and Trade**: Considering global politics (e.g. EU membership; climate change policy; China-US relations and technological differences), how might diplomacy and trade turn out differently?
- **Epidemiology**: SARS and MERS haven't yet existed in healthcare systems' minds. How would they react to COVID-19?

Crisis

- How would global policies be different?
- How would daily life change?

Post-crisis

- How would life in 2020 be different?

Please advise if there's a better community to ask this. I'm just intensely curious about how policy and life may have been different, and feel this is a fascinating thought experiment for the SE community as well.

Comment: Welcome to worldbuilding. Too many questions in one post (we want one question per post) and each of them is too broad, since it requires more than one book to answer it. you can find more info in the [help].

Comment: Then it would be Covid-99

Comment: Your edit has not reduced the number of questions or narrowed the scope. Without a further edit it's not likely to be re-opened.